# Background div menu issue

Tags: html, css, menu, background, jsfiddle

I want to make a menu with a colored background. I use the simple "background" or "background-color" on the div containing the  of my menu but I don't see any color. I know it's dumb but I'm really stuck..

Here is the HTML :

```
 <header class="menu-top">
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a>Home</a></li>
            <li><a>Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a>Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</header>
```

Here is the JSFIDDLE : https://jsfiddle.net/szf1xksv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative could be to use:

```
.menu > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

This will preserve the height of the list items.

Comment: It works, but it causes other problems. For instance, the auto space the browser adds between inline blocked items. floating fixes that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since the list items in your menu are floated, the menu loses it's height.
You need to clear the float after the container. A simple way to do so:

```
.menu:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

[Updated fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/szf1xksv/1/)